# Stuck at Verify kubectl configuration

Tags: configuration, mac-osx, kubernetes, terminal

I'm using Mac Terminal and I'm stuck at the "Verify kubectl configuration", whereas when I run this command --> kubectl cluster-info as the result:-

E0331 23:39:48.601633   27402 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0331 23:39:48.602018   27402 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0331 23:39:48.603144   27402 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0331 23:39:48.604346   27402 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0331 23:39:48.605472   27402 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused

I have tried to re-configured by using this command --> kubectl cluster-info dump - still cannot work. It stated here that I need to install "MiniKube" using Binary Download but have error --> curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16375)

Then I tried downloading using Brew but the error -> Warning: formula.jws.json: update failed, falling back to cached version.
Error: Cannot download non-corrupt https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json!

How to solve this problem? Kindly help me, thank you.

Comment: Hi jng77 welcome to S.F. that "0 != 16375" sure does look like your disk is full. Regarding the localhost:8080, unless you by some stellar coincidence happen to be running kubernetes on localhost:8080 of your **Mac** then of course it's not going to work; what are you expecting to happen here?

Comment: @mdaniel, thanks for your feedback. I wanted to run the Hyperledger Fabric Chaincode - that is my purpose. Since my disk is full, can I use Kubernetes Dashboard instead? If yes, but I do have a problem that is Host/Port for server localhost:8080 was refused - did I specify the right host or port? --> Do you know how to solve this? I'm open to your suggestion. Thank you.